Sony RX100 Menu/Focus issue
UPDATE: I (partially) disassembled the camera, and have resolved the focus motor issue. The mode selction issue still persists.
I purchased a 2nd hand RX100 off marketplace from interstate for not a lot of money. Paid via bank transfer (so no protection), and the camera arrived this afternoon. It turns out there's an issue with the mode selection dial (I expect), and possibly the focus motor. See video below.
https://youtu.be/HfEhdqfN9aU
(Description: Video shows the mode selection menu showing up without turning the dial, and the focus motor noise)
I have experience pulling cameras apart, and the price was cheap enough that I'm really not that disappointed. However, I don't have enough experience with this particular camera to be sure enough about the problem, and I'd prefer not to disassemble it for exploratory purposes.
Based on the video above - what are the most likely causes? Note that the orientation of the camera seems to play a part. If it's pointing up the focus motor goes quiet (not just because it has achieved focus), but the mode selection wheel is still glitchy.
I'm guessing dust or moisture on contacts, but would appreciate a second opinion.
Thanks in advance.

Can't tell you what i tis, but I saw same problems on mine and others sony compacts many years ago (long before this line came out) - enough to put me off them for a while. So it feels like an old problem that wasn't sufficiently problematic to redesign on subsequent models.

I found the solution to the problem - the mode switch was dirty. I followed the video linked HERE to clean it, it was mostly successful, but the problem would recurr occassionally suggesting permenant damage or I missed some dirt while cleaning.
